# Symfony4 Controller __construct() ArgumentCountError

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller

I'm trying to build an MVC application utilising some of the Symfony components (not the full framework though). I'm basically following [create your own framework](https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/index.html) tutorial. 
I set up routes, controller resolver, argument resolver etc. I also set up Symfony dependency injection container and registered my controller as follows:

```
$containerBuilder->register("home_controller", HomeController::class)
    ->setArguments(
        array(
            new Reference("pager"),
            new Reference("student_data_gateway"),
            new Reference("auth_manager")
        )
    );
```

And of course I registered the controller's constructor dependencies also.

```
$containerBuilder->register("auth_manager", AuthManager::class);
$containerBuilder->register("student_data_gateway", StudentDataGateway::class)
    ->setArguments(array(new Reference("connection")));
$containerBuilder->register("pager", Pager::class);
```

When I try to visit the home page, it seems like controller resolver tries to instantiate the HomeController but fails to accomplish it with error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function StudentList\Controllers\HomeController::__construct(), 0 passed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is your controller being instantiated?  In other words, how does your student listing route know to use the home_controller service?  You might need to tweak the controller resolver to pull the controller from the container.  new'ing it won't help.

Comment: @Cerad Ah, so what you are saying is, the native Symfony's controller resolver just instantiates the controller by new'ing it, hence it is not aware of required constructor parameters? So should I just create my own resolver? And if I do create it I assume, that I have to inject the whole service container in the resolver. Isn't it considered a bad practice?

Comment: The Symfony framework resolver is container aware.  You might take a peek at it even if don't want to use it.  Injecting the container is fine when you don't know in advance what services you need out of it.  If it make you feel better then you can call it a service locator.

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this? I have the exact same problem.